# Nginx error: (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi, ansible

I am getting this error in my `nginx-error.log` file:

```
2014/02/17 03:42:20 [crit] 5455#0: *1 connect() to unix:/tmp/uwsgi.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: xx.xx.x.xxx, server: localhost, request: "GET /users HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:/tmp/uwsgi.sock:", host: "EC2.amazonaws.com"
```

The browser also shows a 502 Bad Gateway Error. The output of a `curl` is the same, Bad Gateway html

I've tried to fix it by changing permissions for `/tmp/uwsgi.sock` to 777. That didn't work. I also added myself to the `www-data` group (a couple questions that looked similar suggested that). Also, no dice.

Here is my `nginx.conf` file:

**nginx.conf**

```
worker_processes 1;
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;

events {
  worker_connections  3000; 
}

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on; 
    #tcp_nopush     on; 

    keepalive_timeout  65; 

    #gzip  on; 

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

I am running a Flask application with Nginsx and Uwsgi, just to be thorough in my explanation. If anyone has any ideas, I would really appreciate them.

---

**EDIT**

I have been asked to provide my uwsgi config file. So, I never personally wrote my nginx or my uwsgi file. I followed the guide [here](http://mattupstate.com/python/devops/2012/08/07/flask-wsgi-application-deployment-with-ubuntu-ansible-nginx-supervisor-and-uwsgi.html) which sets everything up using ansible-playbook. The `nginx.conf` file was generated automatically, but there was nothing in `/etc/uwsgi` except a `README` file in both `apps-enabled` and `apps-available` folders. Do I need to create my own config file for uwsgi? I was under the impression that ansible took care of all of those things.

I believe that `ansible-playbook` figured out my uwsgi configuration since when I run this command

```
uwsgi -s /tmp/uwsgi.sock -w my_app:app
```

it starts up and outputs this:

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.1 (64bit) on [Mon Feb 17 20:03:08 2014] ***
compiled with version: 4.7.3 on 10 February 2014 18:26:16
os: Linux-3.11.0-15-generic #25-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 30 17:22:01 UTC 2014
nodename: ip-10-9-xxx-xxx
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /home/username/Project
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
!!! no internal routing support, rebuild with pcre support !!!
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 4548
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /tmp/uwsgi.sock fd 3
Python version: 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 19 2013, 13:52:09)  [GCC 4.8.1]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x1f60260
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 72760 bytes (71 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 3 seconds on interpreter 0x1f60260 pid: 26790 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 26790, cores: 1)
```

Comment: Show the uwsgi configuration and the proxy in nginx.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The permission issue occurs because uwsgi resets the ownership and permissions of /tmp/uwsgi.sock to 755 and the user running uwsgi every time uwsgi starts.

The correct way to solve the problem is to make uwsgi change the ownership and/or permission of /tmp/uwsgi.sock such that nginx can write to this socket. Therefore, there are three possible solutions.

1. Run uwsgi as the www-data user so that this user owns the socket file created by it.

   ```
   uwsgi -s /tmp/uwsgi.sock -w my_app:app --uid www-data --gid www-data
   ```
2. Change the ownership of the socket file so that www-data owns it.

   ```
   uwsgi -s /tmp/uwsgi.sock -w my_app:app --chown-socket=www-data:www-data
   ```
3. Change the permissions of the socket file, so that www-data can write to it.

   ```
   uwsgi -s /tmp/uwsgi.sock -w my_app:app --chmod-socket=666
   ```

I prefer the first approach because it does not leave uwsgi running as root.

The first two commands need to be run as root user. The third command does not need to be run as root user.

The first command leaves uwsgi running as www-data user. The second and third commands leave uwsgi running as the actual user that ran the command.

The first and second command allow only www-data user to write to the socket. The third command allows any user to write to the socket.

I prefer the first approach because it does not leave uwsgi running as root user and it does not make the socket file world-writeable .

Comment: I am facing same problem but i am using `gunicorn` instead of `uwsgi`.How to solve this..?

Comment: @Shiva This question and answer is not about gunicorn. If you have a question about gunicorn, you should post a separate question.

Comment: I had this problem on centOS, and your commands did not work for me.  I used:  `chown -R www-data:www-data /tmp`

Comment: So this basically means you have to run uwsgi as root, correct? Otherwise your uwsgi can't do any chown'ing. What if you want to run uwsgi under a non-root account? (Which I do want because of other permissions issues that arise when using sorl + uwsgi under root)

Comment: Another approach would be to use internet socket instead of unix socket, although unix socket will be more performant for local communication - http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html

Comment: @Roman you've got to check why uwsgi's were not able to give proper access control. In theory it should, unless your configuration is very special.

Comment: @wes I have updated the answer to show the usage of `--uid` and `--gid` options which would run uwsgi as a non-root account. The command using these options still needs to be run as root user but this command launches uwsgi such that it runs as non-root user.

Comment: When I try the first command, I get a bind error that the address is already in use. When I remove the --uid and --gid options it seems to work fine. Any idea what would be causing this?

Comment: @LukeMat You probably need to `rm /tmp/uwsgi.sock` before running `uwsgi` with the `--uid` and `--gid` options. The issue occurred probably because you first ran `uwsgi` as root without the `--uid` and `--gid` options. That caused `/tmp/uwsgi.sock` file to be created with root as the owner. Later when you do run `uwsgi` with the `--uid www-data` and `--gid www-data` options, www-data is unable to write to the socket file because the owner of this file is still root. Therefore, removing the old socket file before using `--uid` and `--gid` options would resolve the issue.

Comment: Yup that turned out to be it! I figured this out a bit after commenting and forgot to come back and give an update. Thank you though!

Comment: With Ubuntu 18.04 I just restart the server and voilà: The problem is gone! (this after trying a lot of things...)

Comment: Be sure to restart nginx service and UWSGI if you try it

Answer (score 19):

While the accepted solution is true there might also SELinux be blocking the access. If you did set the permissions correctly and still get permission denied messages try:

```
sudo setenforce Permissive
```

If it works then SELinux was at fault - or rather was working as expected! To add the permissions needed to `nginx` do:

```
  # to see what permissions are needed.
sudo grep nginx /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow
  # to create a nginx.pp policy file
sudo grep nginx /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M nginx
  # to apply the new policy
sudo semodule -i nginx.pp
```

After that reset the SELinux Policy to Enforcing with:

```
sudo setenforce Enforcing
```

Comment: Thanks @enaut!  selinux was indeed my problem. I've been getting the same error message in the log and once I checked selinux it was in Enforcing mode. I've been tearing my hair out and double checking my file permissions for the past hour when indeed the problem was selinux policy.  Much obliged.

Comment: Great. but you don't need to change `enforce` mode. For more information, visit nginx blog: https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-nginx-plus-with-selinux/

Comment: This is a great solution. After spending hours and rechecking everything, I found this. Just superb!!

Comment: SAved my life :)

Answer (score 12):

Anyone who lands here from the Googles and is trying to run Flask on AWS using the default Ubuntu image after installing nginx and still can't figure out what the problem is:

Nginx runs as user "www-data" by default, but the most common Flask WSGI tutorial from Digital Ocean has you use the logged in user for the systemd service file. Change the user that nginx is running as from "www-data" (which is the default) to "ubuntu" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf if your Flask/wsgi user is "ubuntu" and everything will start working. You can do this with one line in a script:

```
sudo sed -i 's/user www-data;/user ubuntu;/' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Trying to make Flask and uwsgi run as www-data did not work off the bat, but making nginx run as ubuntu worked just fine since all I'm running with this instance is Flask anyhow.

Comment: this saved my life

Comment: Thank you! Worked for me on django+gunicorn+nignx setup as well!

Comment: thanks a lot, I spent hours until found this

Answer (score 5):

```
Nginx connect to .sock failed (13:Permission denied) - 502 bad gateway
```

change the name of the user on the first line in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file.

the default user is `www-data` and change it to root or your username

Comment: It worked on my AWS EC2 Ubuntu 22

Answer (score 4):

You have to set these permissions (`chmod`/`chown`) in uWSGI configuration.

It is the `chmod-socket` and the `chown-socket`.

http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#chmod-socket
http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#chown-socket

Comment: I tried changing the permissions (manually) on the socket to 666, but it still gave me the same error.

Comment: @iurisilvio can you please write the syntax ?

Comment: @MitulShah the accepted answer has the correct syntax already.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's too late, but it might helps to other. I'll suggest to follow [Running flask with virtualenv, uwsgi, and nginx](http://www.markjberger.com/flask-with-virtualenv-uwsgi-nginx/) very simple and sweet documentation.

Must activate your environment if you run your project in virtualenv.

here is the **yolo.py**

```
from config import application

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.run(host='127.0.0.1')
```

And create uwsgi.sock file in /tmp/ directory and leave it blank.
As @susanpal answer said "The permission issue occurs because uwsgi resets the ownership and permissions of /tmp/uwsgi.sock to 755 and the user running uwsgi every time uwsgi starts." it is correct.

So you have to give permission to sock file whenever uwsgi starts.
so now follow the below command

```
uwsgi -s /tmp/uwsgi.sock -w yolo:application -H /var/www/yolo/env --chmod-socket=666
```

A little different command from @susanpal. 
And for *persist connection*, simply add "**&**" end of command

```
uwsgi -s /tmp/uwsgi.sock -w yolo:app -H /var/www/yolo/env --chmod-socket=666 &
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case changing some php permission do the trick

```
sudo chown user:group -R /run/php
```

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: In some cases you should use `sudo chown user:group -R /run/php-fpm`

Answer (score -1):

You should post both nginx and uwsgi configuration file for your application (the ones in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ and /etc/uwsgi/ - or wherever you put them).

Typically check that you have a line similar to the following one in your nginx app configuration:

```
uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock;
```

and the same socket name in your uwsgi config file:

```
socket=/tmp/uwsgi.sock
```

Comment: I don't have that uwsgi config file, see edit to question. Do I need one even though I'm able to run the uwsgi command and it works?

Comment: @AlexChumbley There is no need to create a configuration file if you don't want one. Configuration file makes the setup a bit neater in my opinion because most of the command line options move to the configuration file which means you have to use less options in the command to work with.