# wsgi nginx error: permission denied while connecting to upstream

Tags: sockets, ubuntu, nginx, wsgi, uwsgi

There seem to be many questions on StackOverflow about this but unfortunately nothing has worked for me.

I'm getting a 502 bad gateway on nginx, and the following on the logs: `connect() to ...myproject.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream`

I'm running `wsgi` and `nginx` on `ubuntu`, and I've been following [this guide from Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04). I apparently configured `wsgi` correctly since `uwsgi -s myproject.sock --http 0.0.0.0:8000 --module app --callable app` worked, but I keep getting the `nginx` permission denied error and I have no idea why:

After coming across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21820444/nginx-error-13-permission-denied-while-connecting-to-upstream) and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22071681/permission-denied-nginx-and-uwsgi-socket), I changed the `.ini` file and added the `chown-socket`, `chmod-socket`, `uid` and `gid` parameters (also tried just setting the first two, either or, and a couple of different permission settings --and even the most permissive didn't work).

[This one seemed promising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23948527/13-permission-denied-while-connecting-to-upstreamnginx), but I don't believe `selinux` is installed on my Ubuntu (running `sudo apt-get remove selinux` gives "Package 'selinux' is not installed, so not removed" and `find / -name "selinux"` doesn't show anything). Just in case, though, I tried what [this post](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/how-to-disable-selinux-redhat-fedora-debian-unix/) recommended as well. Uninstalling `apparmor` (`sudo apt-get install apparmor`) didn't work either.

Every time I make a change, I run `sudo service nginx restart`, but I only see the 502 Gateway Error (and the permission denied error when I read the logs).

This is is my `nginx` configuration file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 104.131.110.156;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/user/myproject/web_server/myproject.sock;
    }
}
```

`.conf` file:

```
description "uWSGI server instance configured to serve myproject"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

setuid user
setgid www-data

env PATH=/root/.virtualenvs/my-env/bin
chdir /home/user/myproject/web_server
exec uwsgi --ini /home/user/myproject/web_server/myproject.ini
```

`.ini` file:

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi

master = true
processes = 5

socket = /home/user/myproject/web_server/myproject.sock
chown-socket=www-data:www-data
chmod-socket = 664
uid = www-data
gid = www-data

vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
```

(If it helps, these are the specs of my Digital Ocean machine: `Linux 3.13.0-43-generic #72-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 8 19:35:06 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`)

Please let me know if there's anything I can do, and thank you very much.

Comment: Try placing the socket in /tmp. You could be getting access denied if the nginx user doesn't have permissions to list any of the directories in the socket path. It needs permissions for /home/user, /home/user/myproject, etc

Comment: Thanks for answering! Unfortunately, though, same error: `connect() to unix:/tmp/coaster.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream`

Comment: Pretty sure nginx runs as www-data on Ubuntu, but worth a check... What does /etc/nginx.conf say nginx is running as? Also, what happens if you change php-fpm to use a tcp socket, like 127.0.0.1:9000?

Comment: Yes, I think it's running as `www-data`. I thought that there might be a problem with the permissions, so I changed the owners of the directories under `user/` to the `www-data` user by calling `sudo chown www-data:www-data DIRNAME` but, even after restarting the server and nginx, I still get the same error. I'm also running `nginx` as root, since I call `sudo service nginx restart` while on my root account. And I'm not using PHP, but Flask + WSGI, so I don't know if that applies...

Comment: Derp. Sorry, been answering questions about PHP-FPM recently, lost the context. Regarding the tutorial, I notice that in the init file, you're using not using the same env PATH line that the tutorial is using. After you run `service myproject start` (ie when uwsgi is running), what's the output of `ls -l /home/user/myproject/web_server/myproject.sock`?

Comment: Try to use TCP instead of unix socket, in your case it's `--socket 127.0.0.1:3031` argument and `uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3031;` in nginx configuration. [It's working better anyway](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470109/error-502-in-nginx-php5-fpm/10470827#10470827).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I also followed that tutorial and ran into the same issue. After quite a bit of trial and error, the following steps allowed me to run uWSGI and nginx successfully:

My `nginx.config` file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location / { try_files @yourapplication; }
    location @yourapplication; {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/PATH_TO_PROJECT/PROJECT.sock;
    }
}
```

My `.ini` file wasn't working very well, so I decided to take advantage of uWSGI's extensive arguments that are available. Here's what I used:

```
uwsgi -s /PATH_TO_PROJECT/PROJECT.sock -w wsgi:app -H /PATH_TO_PROJECT/venv --http-processes=4 --chmod-socket=666 --master &
```

Where:

`-s /PATH_TO_PROJECT/PROJECT.sock` = the location of my `.sock` file

`-w wsgi:app` = the location of my `wsgi.py` file and `app` being the name of my Flask object

`-H /PATH_TO_PROJECT/venv` = the location of my virtual environment

`--http-processes=4` = the number of http processes for uWSGI to create

`--chmod-socket=666` = the permissions to set on the socket

`--master` = allow uWSGI to run with its master process manager

`&` = run uWSGI in the background

Comment: And in production situations what happens?

Comment: The `--chmod-socket=666` was what I needed! I even put `chmod-socket=660` in my case.

Comment: Where did you put this command which started with "uwsgi"? On the <service_name>.ini?

Answer (score 9):

After following all the advice in this thread I was still getting permission errors. The finally missing piece was to correct the nginx `user` in the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file:

```
# old: user  nginx;
user  www-data;
```

Comment: FYI ubuntu trusty64 users, nginx is already configured to run as `www-data`.  Hopefully, you read this and I saved you 30 seconds of checking.

Comment: Its worth specifying that this param goes outside http, server, etc. (i.e near or at the top)

Answer (score 9):

To summarize what others have said to solve permission denied error in nginx (which you can look into `/var/log/nginx/error.log` is usually due to the following:

1. you are writing `.sock` file at a place  nginx does not have permission
2. SELinux is causing the problem

To solve 1: First, don't write `.sock` file at `/tmp` as suggested here [server fault answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/463993/nginx-unix-domain-socket-error/464025#464025) because different services see different `/tmp` in fedora. You can write at some place such as `~/myproject/mysocket.sock`. The nginx user must have access to our application directory in order to access the socket file there. By default, CentOS locks down each user's home directory very restrictively, so we will add the nginx user to our user's group so that we can then open up the minimum permissions necessary to grant access.

You can add the nginx user to your user group with the following command. Substitute your own username for the user in the command:

```
sudo usermod -a -G $USER nginx
```

Now, we can give our user group execute permissions on our home directory. This will allow the Nginx process to enter and access content within:

chmod 710 /path/to/project/dir

If the `permission denied` error is still there:
then the hack `sudo setenforce 0` will do the trick.

Comment: `sudo setenforce 0` was indeed the hack.

Answer (score 6):

The path: `unix:/PATH_TO_PROJECT/PROJECT.sock` should be placed in `/tmp` this fixed my problem.

Comment: will not solve problem always see (link)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272943/nginx-cannot-find-unix-socket-file-with-unicorn-no-such-file-or-directory]

Answer (score 5):

**(13: Permission denied)**

This indicates that Nginx was unable to connect to the uWSGI socket because of permissions problems. Usually, this happens when the socket is being created in a restricted environment or if the permissions were wrong. While the uWSGI process is able to create the socket file, Nginx is unable to access it.

This can happen if there are limited permissions at any point between the root directory (/) the socket file. We can see the permissions and ownership values of the socket file and each of its parent directories by passing the absolute path to our socket file to the namei command:

```
namei -nom /PATH_TO_YOUR_SOCKET_FILE/YOUR_SOCKET.sock
```

The output should be similar to this (Your case might have different folder name)

```
f: /run/uwsgi/firstsite.sock
 drwxr-xr-x root  root     /
 drwxr-xr-x root  root     run
 drwxr-xr-x sammy www-data uwsgi
 srw-rw---- sammy www-data firstsite.sock
```

The output displays the permissions of each of the directory components. By looking at the permissions (first column), owner (second column) and group owner (third column), we can figure out what type of access is allowed to the socket file.

In the above example, each of the directories leading up to the socket file have world read and execute permissions (the permissions column for the directories end with r-x instead of ---). The www-data group has group ownership over the socket itself. With these settings, Nginx process should be able to access the socket successfully.

If any of the directories leading up to the socket are not owned by the www-data group or do not have world read and execute permission, Nginx will not be able to access the socket. Usually, this means that the configuration files have a mistake.

So you fix this issue but giving all the upper folder the permission using this command:

```
chmod 755 directory_name
```

I know it is late, but to help others overcome the issue faster, I have posted this answer. Hope it helps, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This may happen if user www-data may not have the permission to create new 
  socket in the given path, so use root user. 
  Relpace user  www-data to user root in nginx.conf;

```
ex: #nginx.conf
#user www-data;
user root;
worker_processes auto;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
.............
```

Comment: That's brute force method which is rarely good idea. My fix for similar issue was to **add** this line to nginx.conf file: `user www-data www-data;`

Answer (score 1):

If you have tested all the permissions and it is still not working then maybe SELinux is enabled, this will cause the same behaviour.

Run `getenforce` and if the result is `Enforcing` then that will not help.

Quick fix is to disable it, `setenforce 0` but a restart is required.

Answer (score 1):

*2 things helped me*

I had correct configuration in nginx I also was seeing /tmp/wsgi.sock with my two eyes in the folder but there was still permission denied or directory not exists:

1. In file `/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service` set `PrivateTmp=false` and restart nginx (do not forget `systemctl daemon reload` to refresh config)
2. Run command `setenforce 0`

*Bonus material:*

`/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --chdir /home/biohazard/myproject -s /tmp/wsgi.sock -w api:app --chmod-socket=777 --master --thunder-lock --http-processes=2` where in `api:app` api stands for `/home/biohazard/myproject/api.py`

And

```
location = /api { rewrite ^ /api/; }
location /api { try_files $uri @api; }
location @api {
  include uwsgi_params;
  uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/wsgi.sock;
}
```

Where nginx is serving my `http://example.org/api` endpoint only

Comment: I forgot how to do it then found my own answer. Thank you me

Answer (score 0):

Check user field on the first line in nginx.conf file. By default it is www-data. Change the name to user root in nginx.conf file if you logged in as root.

Answer (score 0):

I Am Also Getting Same Issue While Deploying Flask Using Nginx And Gunicorn. 
I Solved This Issue By putting .Sock file in /temp folder.

Answer (score 0):

There are many things that can cause this particular error, in my case it was the ownership of my `PROJECT.socket` file that caused it.

Instead of:
`srwxr-xr-x 1 yourusername yourusername     0 Nov  4 22:32 PROJECT.sock`

it should be: `srwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data     0 Nov  4 22:32 PROJECT.sock`

Just run `sudo chown www-data:www-data PROJECT.sock` and that's it.