# nginx Permission denied on Ubuntu

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, permissions, uwsgi

I'm trying to set up my Django app with uWSGI and nginx by following [this guide](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html). I'm able to run my app with Django's development server, as well as being served directly from uWSGI.

I'm running everything on a university managed Ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine, and my user has `sudo` access.

---

**My problem:**
When getting to [this bit](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#basic-nginx-test) of the tutorial, and try to fetch an image, I get a 403 error from nginx.
The [next section](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html#nginx-and-uwsgi-and-test-py) results in a 502.

`/var/log/nginx/error.log` shows

> connect() to unix:///me/myproject/media/image.jpg failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream
>
> connect() to unix:///me/myproject/project.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream

for the 403 and 502, respectively.

I have read multiple questions and guides ([one here](https://serverfault.com/questions/235154/permission-denied-while-reading-upstream), [another here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22071681/permission-denied-nginx-and-uwsgi-socket) and [yet another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21820444/nginx-error-13-permission-denied-while-connecting-to-upstream), and this is not all of them), changed my permissions and even moved my `.sock` to another folder (one of the SO answers recommended that).

What else can I try?

---

**Update:**

I mentioned it in a comment, but I've gotten a *bit* further. A part of the problem was that, apparently, the `/home` directory on my VM is NFS, which messes up a good many permissions.

What I've done:

- I've set up my project in `/var/www/myproject/`
- Run `chown -R me:www-data myproject`
- Run `chmod -R 764 myproject`

My new results:

- Without nginx running:

  - `uwsgi --http :8000 --module myproject.wsgi`
    **works perfectly**
- With nginx running:

  - `uwsgi --socket myproject.sock --module myproject.wsgi --chmod-socket=664`
    **gives me a 502**
  - `uwsgi --ini myproject.ini`
    **gives me a 502**

So now it's not a general permission issue, it's definitely an issue with nginx...

---

**Update #2:**
For the moment, everything is working when `other` has `read-write` permissions on the socket, and `read-execute` permissions on the rest of the project.
So nginx is not recognized as it should... I've double-checked, and nginx is running as the `www-data` user, which is the group-owner of my entire project, and which has `read-execute` permissions, just as `other` now has.

---

Here's my (updated) `nginx.conf`

```
# myproject_nginx.conf

# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    # server unix:///path/to/your/mysite/mysite.sock; # for a file socket
    server unix:///var/www/myproject/myproject.sock;
    # server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      8000;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name my.ip.goes.here; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /var/www/myproject/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
        alias /var/www/myproject/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /var/www/myproject/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

And here's my (updated) `uwsgi.ini`

```
# myproject_uwsgi.ini file
[uwsgi]

# Django-related settings
# the base directory (full path)
chdir          = /var/www/myproject
# Django's wsgi file
module         = myproject.wsgi
# the virtualenv (full path)
home           = /var/www/myenv

# process-related settings
master         = true
# maximum number of worker processes
processes      = 10
# the socket (full path)
socket         = /var/www/myproject/myproject.sock
# ... with appropriate permissions - may be needed
chmod-socket   = 666
uid            = me
gid            = www-data
# clear environment on exit
vacuum         = true
```

Comment: When you try to access a static file or media file, they should be served directly through nginx, therefor you should not have to call your socket. It seems like the `location /media` does not work, can you share what URL you are calling ?

Comment: @Thom: Both the IP and the port are specified in `nginx.conf` (`129.214.113.109` and `8000`), and my Django-app is called "grader". So the URL I'm trying to access is `129.214.113.109:8000/grader`.

Comment: Ok then you should try to change your `location` statements by `location /grader/static { ...` and `location /grader/media {...`

Comment: No change. I don't think that nginx has any trouble _finding_ the file(s), it's just that it can't _access_ it/them.

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, most of the permission problems around web server are by accessing file which is owned by root, but Apache (nginx) is running under `www-data` user.

Try running `sudo chown www-data -R /path/to/your/data/folder`.

Comment: Hum... Weird... I tried changing both the owner and the group (as well as only the group) to `www-data` (which I am a part of), but neither `chown` nor `chgrp` works?! I get **_Operation not permitted_**. I also tried rebooting, because I read somewhere that Linux groups doesn't take effect until after you log out and in again. But, alas...

Comment: Welp. The VM I am using apparently uses an NFS `/home`, which messes with permissions. But I set up the whole thing again in a local folder, changed owner to `me:www-data`, and set permissions to 777 for good measure. Buuuut no change.

Answer (score 0):

As the tutorial said:

> You may also have to add your user to nginx’s group (which is probably
>   www-data), or vice-versa, so that nginx can read and write to your
>   socket properly.

Try that and see what happens.

As well I wouldn't recommend you doing things with sudo or as root, do it as a normal user and place the permission as it get necessary, otherwise you might end up in a situation that Nginx or uWSGI need to do something with the files and they are owned by root.

Comment: And I think I've tried most things both with and without `sudo`.